Выбор детского кресла при формировании заказа
помогите разобраться в api заказа яндекс такси. Я передаю параметр req = childchair  в строку формирования заказа, однако не нашел документацию по передачи размеров этого кресла ( 3 года NxN , 5 лет ...), а так же количества ( 1 или 2). Такой функционал присутствует в приложении , но не описан для api
